# Is Google Admin Token Audit Log Broken?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-admin-audit-api

I used the Google admin token audit logs and they have not been returning data as the events show up. This has been going on. Is this a known issue with the audit api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer with this [Admin console audit log support page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4579579?hl=en). You may find that your Admin console reports and audit logs are not fully populated with the latest data. Be noted that reports do not reflect real-time data, and some reports may take longer to display updated information. There are specific [lag times](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7061566) before collected data is available.

It is also stated that retrieving report or audit log data for very old dates or large time ranges may take so much time that once results are available the most recent log entry may no longer be fresh. For applications that require real-time log monitoring use a small time range.